# TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of print statement', got 'news' when use jinja and jquery.tmpl.js at the same time

Tags: jquery, python

I got

> TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of print statement', got 'news'

when use jinja and jquery.tmpl.js at the same time. Here is my code

```
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
{{each(i,news) news}}
......
{{/each}}
</script>
```

I think the `{{` in `{{each(i,news) news}}` is conflict to `{{` in jinja, so I change `{{each(i,news) news}}` to `{%each(i,news) news %}`.

But jquery tmpl doesn't work.

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I find a way to solve it.

```
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
{% raw %}
{{each(i,news) news}}
......
{{/each}}
{% endraw %}
</script>
```